# How to update EKS cluster ID information as output inside terraform state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-aws-modules

I have deployed EKS cluster. At this time in order to use its cluster id I was using this code

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_id
}
```

After deployment I have refactored my code into modules and now I using output for providers

outputs.tf (this file is within same directory as eks.tf which uses [eks module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/18.30.3))

```
output "eks_cluster_id" {
  value = module.eks.cluster_id
}
```

providers.tf in root module

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = module.base.eks_cluster_id
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "cluster" {
  name = module.base.eks_cluster_id
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority[0].data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
}
```

Now the problem is that deployment without modules didnt have modules so terraform state does not have this cluster id information. if I try to do terraform plan (after refactoring into modules ) it fails since cluster_id information is not there to connect to kubernetes cluster

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority[0].data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
}
```

How to solve this?

I think if I use  `terraform apply -target=module.base.aws_eks_cluster.this` this will update the output information. However when I tried this it is destroying the cluster which is already created.

Comment: Are you defining any other outputs except for the EKS cluster ID? For example, the endpoint and cert data?

Comment: No I am not defining any other outputs. Before refactoring the code the code was working with `data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster` data

Comment: I could come up with an answer that would help with the problem you have if there were any outputs defined in the EKS module though.

Comment: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/18.30.3/examples/complete?tab=outputs Technically cluster_id is already defined in EKS module as an output I an just using that value in `outputs.tf` and then in data resource in `providers.tf`. But please if you have an answer I will appreciate that.

Comment: Are you calling the module as `module "base"` or something different?

Answer (score 0):

What I have found is working a bit better is using a different approach to configuring the [`kubernetes` provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs#exec-plugins):

```
data "aws_region" "selected" {}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data)
  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1"
    args        = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", module.eks.cluster_id, "--region", data.aws_region.selected.name]
    command     = "aws"
  }
}
```

The important thing to note here is that you can use any additional options in `args` that the AWS CLI command provides. As a side note, this works only with AWS CLI v2. Additionally, using it this way will fall back to the **default** profile. If you are using a profile other than default, you can add the `--profile, <profile name>` in the `args` list. Finally, to be able to use this cluster and perform actions on it, you need to update the `.kubeconfig` file. This is achieved by running the following [AWS CLI command](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.0.34/reference/eks/update-kubeconfig.html):

```bash
aws eks update-kubeconfig --name <cluster name> [--profile <named profile>]
```

There is an `--alias` parameter available, which if omitted, will default to the cluster ARN. Also note the following:

> When `update-kubeconfig` writes a configuration to a kubeconfig file, the current-context of the kubeconfig file is set to that configuration.

so make sure to check the context prior to applying any Kubernetes manifest files.